# How to capture login through JMeter into a Web application which has third party auth app integrated such as OKTA?

Tags: jmeter

My web application is using OKTA as a third-party authentication tool while login. I want to do load testing of this app through JMeter.

I captured a scenario which does following:

1. Access URL
2. Login into app
3. Go to Required page.
4. Update the data and Save it.

Script is capturing session token and I handled correlation. The script is showing all request pass while playing back but the data is not getting updated.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Both my app and OKTA Auth app is on Cloud AWS platform.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok. Will take care of your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter automatically considers [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful so "all request pass" may mean nothing if your server replies with positive HTTP Status code. Most likely you are hitting the login page with all your requests.

I would recommend running your test with [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener enabled and inspect request and especially response details to ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing. Additionally you can add [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)(s) to inspect JMeter Variables and Properties names and values at different stages of your test. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article to learn more about how to get to the bottom of your JMeter test script failure.

Once you figure out what was wrong you might want to add few [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions) implementing smarter pass/fail criteria for your test and avoid "false positive" results in the future.